# Facebook - Likes hidden in timeline visible in stream?

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-like

If I like any page on Facebook, it will normally automatically appear on my timeline and my friends will be able to see this on my profile and in their news feed. Now I have hidden the tab 'likes' and activated the option on my timeline not to show my likes.
If I like a new page now, will it appear in the news stream of my friends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook is intentionally vague on this issue. See [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/171783462899295)

Normally if it doesn't appear on the timeline, it will not appear in a news feed. So, if you choose not to share something and it doesn't appear, it won't go to news feed. If it does, however, come to timeline, you have to implement the audience [control](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/225435534134033).

What you need to do is see if it shows up on your timeline. If it does, you can delete it or [change the audience](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/225435534134033)

If in doubt, always turn on [timeline review](https://www.facebook.com/help/168229546579373) to stop things from getting through.

Comment: I stated above that I have activated the option on my timeline not to show my likes. I simply want to know if this option also affects the news feed of my friends. Maybe it does not show up on my timeline, but I am not sure if it might maybe show up in the news feed of my friends.

Comment: @Birk See updates in answer for clarification

Comment: "Normally if it doesn't appear on the timeline, it will not appear in a news feed." It's not that simple. If I commented a post of a friend X, it will not show up on my timeline but some other friend Y of mine might see in his news feed that I have commented the post of X. Now I am curious if that is the case with likes, too.

Comment: Absolutely, you can't control anything except your own timeline to news feed. Implement timeline review to prevent tags and whatnot, but if someone has access to a post that you do anything to, they can see it because the settings are for that post, not your additions

Comment: @Birk sorry for the confusion, the initial question is related to **pages**, not posts, so I didn't address the issue that you intended.

Comment: Yes, but I am explicitly asking for pages in this case. Why should one getting notified about me liking a page that he/she does not like?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9798/discussion-between-raystafarian-and-birk)